# Azure pipelines Stage variable fails with no error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to get the new stage variables to work.Here is my stripped down example:-

```
stages:
- stage: firstStage
  jobs:
  - job: varSetJob
    pool: 
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |

            Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=DeployEnvironment;isOutput=true]AnEnvironment")
            Write-Output ("vso[task.setvariable variable=DeployEnvironment;isOutput=true]AnEnvironment")


        name: varStep

      - script: echo $(varStep.deployEnvironment)
        name: show

- stage: secondStage
  dependsOn: firstStage
  variables:
  - name: DeployEnvironmentstage
    value: $[ stageDependencies.firstStage.varSetJob.outputs['varStep.DeployEnvironment'] ]

  jobs:
  - job: showvar
    pool: 
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
      - script: echo $(DeployEnvironmentstage)
        name: show
```

This pipeline fails to start the second step and no logs are made, running in diagnostic mode.

[image: build failure]

I've checked the azure devops version and it is on the latest sprint version.

Has anyone had this working yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the variables under a Job:

```
- stage: secondStage
  dependsOn: firstStage
  jobs:
  - job: showvar
    pool: 
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    variables:
      - name: DeployEnvironmentstage
        value: $[ stageDependencies.firstStage.varSetJob.outputs['varStep.DeployEnvironment'] ]
    steps:
      - script: echo $(DeployEnvironmentstage)
        name: show
```

Comment: This runs through. But I want the variable at stage scope to be able to set an environment name. At job scope it does not resolve. it creates and environment called "$(DeployEnvironmentstage)"

Comment: Runtime expressions are designed to be used in the conditions of jobs. You need to put it under a job.

Comment: That is a shame It seems that there is no way to programmatically determine an environment during a pipeline run.

My pipeline is multi-use in that it builds different editions depending on a setting or a script in the first job. The target environment is different per edition.